# Display results from On-Premise SharePoint in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I am using BAInsight Custom connectors to crawl/index SQL Databases in my SharePoint On-Prem environment. We also have SharePoint Online tenant and I have enabled hybrid federated search results in SharePoint Server. I now want to also display the results from custom connectors to be displayed in SharePoint Online. I tried setting up a new result source but am unable to get all managed properties that are there in SharePoint Server. Any pointers / help.

Comment: You say you are using hybrid, did you create a Cloud SSA for crawling your on-premises content? If so you manage all the properties in the Tenant Search Service.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Why do I need to crawl my on-premise content source in the cloud again when I am already crawling it on-premise. Also I cannot crawl SQL data source directly as I am using custom connector to crawl my SQL content source.

Comment: I didn't say "crawl again", I asked a question. You are using a confusing mix of terminology so I am trying to clarify so I can help. You use both the term "hybrid" and the term "federation" which is it? Are you using Federated Query (not hybrid crawl) or are you using the Cloud SSA (hybrid crawl)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Is should be Federated search as I cannot crawl SQL data source from cloud. I am already crawling this data source on premise via custom connectors (BA Insight).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Hybrid Search rather than query federation? You can crawl all of your on-prem content and build one index in SPO. Then you manage the result sources and Managed Properties in SPO.

If you stay with query federation, you can use the on-prem managed properties in your queries of on-prem content, but you will have to write them by hand since they are not "known" to SPO.

Comment: Can you point me to some reference articles / blogs for the same? I have an enterprise search farm on-premise for crawling custom content sources via connectors and an online tenant for SharePoint, OneDrive & Yammer. I am trying to avoid crawling same content twice.

Comment: Right. With the Cloud Index you just crawl the on-prem content and store the index in Office 365. (SPO). https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn720906.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I think now I understand the scenario. I was not fully aware about Cloud SSA since we were using federated search. Now since the Index will be stored only in cloud, how should I go about crawling and indexing custom content with connectors like BAInsight. Should I create all managed/crawl properties in cloud so that I can query them from on-prem / cloud?

Comment: Yes, the on prem crawler will use the connectors and crawl BCS. Then the Cloud SSA sends it up to SPO.

Comment: Thanks. Let me test this over and I'll up date the thread with my findings.

Comment: ...and the update has not happened yet... - unfortunately

Comment: What update are you referring to? The Cloud SSA is released for both SP 2013 and SP 2016.